# How to change a color of the title of the selected tab at TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-styles, android-tablayout

I want to change a color of this area behind the icons at TabLayout, only a line with icons. I also need to change this pink line under the title, but I can't find appropriate parameters at style. My style:

```
  <style name="AppTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">4dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">6dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">6dp</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/AppTabTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/darkPurple</item>
  </style>

  <!-- for text -->
  <style name="AppTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
  </style>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the tab background color, create a [selector](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) and put that selector's resource ID like:

`<item name="tabBackground">@drawable/selector_name</item>`.

For the pink underline, change the color in

`<item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/your_new_color</item>`

Answer (score 2):

try this use following property of  tab-layout

```
app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorBlack"// it set Selected tab underline color
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"// it set Selected tab  text color
app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent"// it set tab text color
```

Answer (score 2):

Add atribute in xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    ....
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
    ...
    />
```

And create in drawable folder, tab_color_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_unselected"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

## try this

- Create `bg_color` in your `drawable folder`

---

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/timecard"
    android:color="@color/colorText" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/timecard_selected"
    android:color="@color/colorSkyBlue"/>

<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/timecard"
    android:color="@color/colorText"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/timecard_selected"
    android:color="@color/colorSkyBlue"/>

<!-- Pressed -->
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/timecard"
    android:color="@color/colorText"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/timecard_selected"
    android:color="@color/colorSkyBlue" />
```

---

- and add this in your `layout` like this

---

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:tabStripEnabled="false"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:tabContentStart="0dp"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/bg_color"
            app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
            app:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorSkyBlue"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorSkyBlue" />
```